# Implement logic between different instances of the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I want to implement some logic between different instances of the same class but I don't how to properly do it. Both review and advice are required.

It is best to start with an example. Supposed I have a class `foo`. There are three attributes in this class - `id`, `group` and `nitem`.

The logic to be implemented is that the instance of `foo` if under the same group should have the same number of items (i.e. `nitem`).

Some may have noticed that I have already implemented a piece of logic between instances which is counting the number of instances via `foo._id`. But you can also understand easily how naive this method is. If you create three instances of `foo` and delete the middle instance. The last instance will still have an `id=3`.

```
class foo(object):
    _id = 0
    def __init__(self, group, nitem):
        foo._id += 1
        self.id = foo._id
        self.group = group
        self.nitem = nitem

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = foo(1, 100)
    b = foo(2, 10) #no error. Different groups can have different nitem.
    c = foo(1, 10) # I want this to raise error.Same groups can't have different nitem.
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `__new__` to perform checks upon object instantiation:

[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**new**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

```py
from typing import Any


class foo(object):
    _groups = {}

    def __new__(cls, group, nitem) -> Any:
        if group not in cls._groups:
            cls._groups[group] = nitem
        if cls._groups[group] == nitem:
            return super().__new__(cls)
        raise ValueError('mismatched group and nitems')

    def __init__(self, group, nitem):
        self.group = group
        self.nitem = nitem


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = foo(1, 100)
    b = foo(2, 10)
    c = foo(2, 100)
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 23, in <module>
    c = foo(2, 100)
  File "app.py", line 12, in __new__
    raise ValueError('mismatched group and nitems')
ValueError: mismatched group and nitems
```

it raises error when creating `c`

Comment: what if an instance has zero reference count and is erased from memory by the garbage collection of Python, how can I update the `cls._groups` correspondingly?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a limited number of groups defined with a specific `nitem` number, you can simply use a dictionary with the key being the group name and item being the number of `nitem` that the group is allowed to have. Then in the constructor you can simply utilise the dictionary to allocate a default value to the `nitem` corresponding to the group.

An example is this:

```
group_dict = {"students": 5,
              "teachers": 10}

class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, group, nitem=group_dict[str(group)]):
        self.group = group
        self.nitem = nitem
```